# C++ shared_pointer with templated classes and dynamic dispatch

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, shared-ptr

I have a C++ code where I try to create a `shared_pointer` on a derived class. When the `shared_pointer` is created, the dynamic dispatch stops working.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "Print from Base" << endl;
    }

};

template <typename T>
class Child : public Base<T>
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "Print from Child" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class TestClass: public Base<T>
{
public:
    TestClass<T> (Base<T> &b)
    {
        b.print();
        shared_ptr<Base<T>> sptr = make_shared<Base<T>> (b);
        sptr->print();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child<int> child;
    TestClass<int> cl(child);
}
```

In the copy constructor of `TestClass`, I first call the `print()` method, which works just fine. Once the `shared_pointer` is created, the method refers to the base class.

The output is the following:

```
Print from Child
Print from Base
```

Question: How can I create the shared pointer and not lose the dynamic dispatch functionality?

Comment: This is because you're constructing a new base class, not a new child class with a copy constructor.

Comment: sounds almost like this person is looking for `shared_from_this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_shared` doesn't make an existing thing shared; it makes a new shared thing, with the type you give it.

It's effectively like this (pseudo-code only!):

```
template <typename T>
shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args...)
{
    shared_ptr<T> newPtr = new T(args...);
    return newPtr;
}
```

In this case you're creating a `Base<int>`, that will be shared. It is not a child of anything. It's a sliced copy of your `Child<int>`.

Nothing in `TestClass` knows that you wanted a `Child<int>`, or even knows that `Child<int>` exists as a type.

You could do `shared_ptr<Base<T>> sptr = &b` to obtain a shared_ptr to an existing object. Unfortunately said object is not dynamically allocated, so that's not going to go well.

It would really be better to be consistent with your object ownership semantics. Your `main` function can do `auto ptr = make_shared<Child<int>>()`, then pass the resulting shared pointer into anything that expects a `shared_ptr<Child<int>>` or a `shared_ptr<Base<int>>`.

Without knowing what you're actually trying to do, I cannot make any more specific suggestions.

Comment: You could use a custom destructor for the `shared_ptr` that does nothing to not cause any issues when ref count is 0 but that would be completely pointless and cause a ton of overhead and performance loss for zero gain.

Comment: Yep, exactly so